# How can I make TalkBack ignore an element while still reading its content description when a parent element is focused?

Tags: android, accessibility

Imagine I have a Labeled Checkbox containing two views. A text view on the left describing the field (the label) and a checkbox on the right.

- On focus of the parent LabeledCheckbox, I want the textview's text to be read along with the checkbox's content description.
- I don't want the individual views (text and checkbox) to be focusable. The parent LabeledCheckbox should read the information from both views and onClick clicks the checkbox (already done).

I know that android:importantForAccessibility makes elements not focusable, but it also ignores their content descriptions. Basically: what's an alternative way to disallow focus that won't ignore content descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [CheckBox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox) element, you can set text to it and it will be read with the text and the state of the checkbox together.

If you are making your own checkbox by using a checkbox and a separate TextView, then you have to set your own content description on the parent view instead.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I eventually realized–I set the individual views as notImportantForAccessibility and just put the whole content description on the parent.